# “The first, it is” or “First, it is”?

Tags: definite-article, pronouns, ordinals, transitions, discourse-markers

In the following sentence, Does the "the" article come before the "first" word?

> I have two reasons for my claim. **The** first, it is . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd better say
"The first one - it is ... *(first reason)* ... The second one - ...*(second reason)*..."
But if you have to keep the original text I think "The" isn't necessary.
"I have two reasons for my claim. First - it is ...*(first reason)*... Second - ...*(second reason)*..."

Comment: You are correct in saying that the article isn't necessary—but I would never suggest your initial "better" rephrasing to anyone. It's not at all natural.

Comment: Alex, "had better (do something) means "If you know what's good for you." You'd better take an umbrella. It's going to rain. I'd better post that letter, it's important.

Answer (score -1):

The first is..  Not: The first it is.

"It" means "the first"  It's like saying: The car it is old.

Comment: Someone care to mention WHY they marked this answer down?!!